# Ubuntu 12.04.5 to 14.04.5 do-release-upgrade: "No new release found"

Tags: 14.04, 12.04, server, upgrade, do-release-upgrade

A number of my servers were upgraded from 12.04 to 14.04 early 2015 (Note this is Oct-2016) without issue.
Updated dozens of similar systems years ago and Generally, I've never had an issue with this.

I have one server that I'm trying to do now and it's giving me the "no new release found" error.

Just curious if I'm missing something or if there was a change over the past year or so in the update method. Do you have any thoughts?

$ sudo do-release-upgrade

```
Checking for a new Ubuntu release
No new release found
```

$ lsb_release -a

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 12.04.5 LTS
Release:        12.04
Codename:       precise
```

/etc/apt/source.list:

```
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise main restricted
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise main restricted
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates main restricted
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates main restricted
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise universe
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise universe
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates universe
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates universe
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise multiverse
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise multiverse
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates multiverse
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates multiverse


deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-backports main restricted universe multiverse

deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-security main restricted
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-security main restricted
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-security universe
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-security universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-security multiverse
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-security multiverse
```

/etc/update-manager/release-upgrades

```
# Default behavior for the release upgrader.

[DEFAULT]
# Default prompting behavior, valid options:
#
#  never  - Never check for a new release.
#  normal - Check to see if a new release is available.  If more than one new
#           release is found, the release upgrader will attempt to upgrade to
#           the release that immediately succeeds the currently-running
#           release.
#  lts    - Check to see if a new LTS release is available.  The upgrader
#           will attempt to upgrade to the first LTS release available after
#           the currently-running one.  Note that this option should not be
#           used if the currently-running release is not itself an LTS
#           release, since in that case the upgrader won't be able to
#           determine if a newer release is available.
Prompt=lts
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, but just resolved it.

Please make sure you do this before the real upgrade.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Resolve issues that you encounter at this point first.
Then you might encounter "No new release found" when you run `sudo do-release-upgrade`. Try `sudo apt-get install update-manager` before `sudo do-release-upgrade`. This fixed my issue.